# I have an htaccess url problem

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to create user profile URL like

```
www.example.com/username
```

so I have add this in .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([_A-Z0-9a-z-+]+)$ index.php?p=home&username=$1 [S=1]
```

but it will conflict with my about page URL. My about URL is

```
RewriteRule ^about/$ index.php?p=about [S=1]
```

but it will redirect to user profile page.

Can any body tell me what to do?

Comment: If you have more rules then please provide them in your question. Then we can rearrange the rules in proper order (maybe the best way) so they will work nicely together. Another solution -- add exclusion for your username rewrite rule -- just like Bob Vale suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(about)
```

before the username RewriteRule